# How to parse specific data from a serial input on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, serial-port, gps

I am using a GPS module for precise positioning. It's going to be autonomous and we need to make a fail-safe in case the GPS loses its rtk fix.

To do that, I am employing a Raspberry Pi 4b connected via UART to the GPS module. The GPS sends a message, GNGGA, where one of the parameters informs the status of the fix, then the Raspberry Pi monitors these parameters and keeps checking if the fix type stays as rtk fixed and sends an alert if not.

So far I have the code below that connects the Raspberry Pi to the module

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
import serial

ser=serial.Serial(
        port='/dev/serial/serial01'
        baudrate=460800
        parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
        stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
        bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
        timeout=1
)
counter=0

while 1:
        x=ser.readline()
```

If I print x, I get something like this:

```
�6ȶ< �>�r�%���a���5��PFpx���� zR�b�qI��@ǃy�v����$p���`X�w�?Ĉ*�����>��G;
                                                                       A��� 
                O���������r[���nlB>X$GNGGA,202538.90,2156.26451,S,04753.49406,W,1,12,0.52,751.9,M,-6.2,M,,*53
```

The unreadable part of the code is some other messages the GPS needs, while the readable part is the part I want to extract.

I believe I know the logic behind what needs to be done: I need to recognize the start of this string, and since the size of this is fixed, I should be able to use its length to extract the whole string or just the parameter I need.

I don't have much experience dealing with serial communication with python so I don't know how to employ this logic. After a few hours of trial and error, I managed to find the start of the string with a few if's, but I don't how to go from here.

Can anyone give some advice?

Comment: You forgot to post your relevant code.

Comment: *"I want to use the rpi to listen to the serial output"* -- Data that is received is called "input" rather than *"output"*.

Comment: *"not human-readable, and ... human readable"* -- It's all just data, i.e numbers.  Some of it is *"human readable"* because the decoding using the ASCII mapping result in portions where you recognize the character patterns.